# Setting text color with a JColorChooser

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I'm trying to make a text editor with a JTextPane, but i'm having trouble with setting the selected texts color. Here is the best  could come up with (but, obviously, not working):

```
    JMenuItem button = new JMenuItem("Set Color");
    toolbar.add(button);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener( ) {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(frame,"Choose a color", getBackground());
            textPane.getSelectedText().StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction("color",c);
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions on how to get that to work? Or a better method of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSelectedText()` just returns a normal string containing the selected text; you cannot use it to modify the attributes of the text.

I would start by using [`SimpleAttributeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/SimpleAttributeSet.html) and [`StyleConstants`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyleConstants.html) to generate the colour attribute, then apply it to the selected portion of your text:

```
SimpleAttributeSet attr = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(attr, c);
textPane.setCharacterAttributes(attr, false);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for setting the color of the selected text, now the only problem is that I can only set the color by selecting more text and setting it to a different color (rather than just selecting a new color and typing with that). Any suggestions on how to remedy that?

Comment: @user485418: See my edited answer. It's actually simpler than before and I believe it should work for both selected and typed text. :)